# C++ : How to find all Graph Way

Tags: c++, graph

I want Receive a Graph Like a Matrix and find all ways that we can go from e.g( point a to point b).
I use a Recursive Function

### (my Graph have 3 point ,all of them are Connected together  so matrix is this)

```
0    1    1
1    0    1
1    1    0
```

if I want go from point 0 to point 2 I can go as
     `0 > 1 > 2`  or  `0 > 2`

Because I can not send matrix to function I change it to array

```
int way(int G2[],int point)
{
if(point!=lastp(point))
PPoint(point);//save point in stack
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
int index=0;
int Graf[size][size];
for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
{
    for(int j=0;j<size;j++)
    {
        Graf[i][j]=G2[index];
        index+=1;
    }
}

 ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////   
if(Lpoint[temp-1]==endp)  //Lpoint is stack & endp is end point
{
    pop(); //write all stack 
    point=Lpoint[temp];
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////   

cout<<"\nforstart\n";
for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
{
    Graf[i][i]=0;

    if((Graf[point][i]!=0)&&(i!=lastp(i)))
    {
        cout<<"\nif 1 done\n";
        way(G2,i);
    }
    if(((i==size-1)&&(Graf[point][i]==0))||((i==size-1)&&(i==lastp(i))&&(temp!=0)))
    {
        cout<<"\nif 2 done\n";
        goback();
        way(G2,Lpoint[temp]);
    }   
 }//endfor
}
```

it's like  to a Unlimited loop

all code is [here](https://ufile.io/y3ndz)

Comment: What about going 0 > 1 > 0 > 1 > 2 or 0 > 1 > 0 > 1 > 0 > 1 > 0 > 2? Aren't there an infinite number of paths? Maybe you mean paths without loops?

Comment: i want havent Repeat

Comment: Research the following: "depth first search" and "breadth first search". Either will work. You can avoid loops by setting a visited flag on the node, just as one example.